# Skipping errors with sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

When i type `sudo apt-get update` I get

```
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:5 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:7 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'release/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'release' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

What `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` gives me

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` you may need to remove the numix ppa if it's not compatible with focal

Comment: I removed the numix and it seems to be working but ill add the cat /etc/apt/sources.list too.

Comment: Read your output: Delete the Numix PPA causing all the warnings. Optionally, then re-install the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

`W:` means *warning*, a non-fatal error. The process continues, but you really should fix the problem.

Real errors (`E:`) are fatal and cannot be skipped.

Comment: And how to fix those errors?

Comment: @an4s911 you fix the *problem* by deleting that Numix PPA from the sources.